# How to get values of textbox and dropdownlist controls in a gridview on a button click event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

On the page load there will be gridview with a default row....there is a button with a + sign at the bottom...on the button click i want to create a new rows in the grid..before that i need to make sure that all fields have values.But I am getting null values..

[image: I want to get the value of textbox and dropdownlist controls (which are in a gridview)]

My code is:

```
TextBox name_value = ((TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[0].FindControl("TextBox1"));
            TextBox age_value = ((TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[0].FindControl("TextBox2"));
            DropDownList sex_value = ((DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[0].FindControl("DropDownList1"));
            DropDownList berth_value = ((DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[0].FindControl("DropDownList2"));
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure the name of the dropdown/textbox in EditItemplate field matches correctly with the one given in code

Comment: @sun - In what event you want to get the values ?

Comment: are you writing this code on a button click or what?

Comment: @Bibhu...i want to make sure that all fields have values...thats all

Comment: @sun - That means you want to do validation of each feild ? right ? If so then tell us, that validation will happen in which event .

Comment: what is the problem you are facing

Answer (score 0):

Please write this code at end of the code 
`Gridview1.EditIndex-1` not sure EditIndex or Edititemindex please try it may be help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a condition

```
if(name_value.Text!="" && age_value.Text && sex_value.Text && berth_value.Text)
{

//action

}
```